# UITextView - NSTextAttachment

Tags: swift

How do we render authenticated inline images in UITextView from an HTML string?
Also resize downloaded image with ratio.

```
_attributedString.beginEditing()
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
                        attachment.bounds.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
                        attachment.downloadFile(urlPathString: previewItems[index].urlString, placehoderImage: defaultImage)
                        let inlineAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
                        _attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: nsRange, with: inlineAttributedString)
                        _attributedString.endEditing()
    
extension NSTextAttachment {
    
    func downloadFile(urlPathString: String, placehoderImage: UIImage?) {
        
        NetworkHandler.sharedInstance.downloadFile(urlPathString: urlPathString) { attachment in
            
            self.bounds.size = attachment.size
            self.image = attachment
            
        } failure: { errorString in
            
            ShowUserMessageUtil.showUserMessageOnRootViewController(text: errorString)
            self.image = placehoderImage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your goal? Does `NSAttrtributedString` init with HTML not working for you when there is image? What's your exact issue? Do you have a HTML sample, and output/expected given?

Comment: Want to add some key in the header of the HTML image tag URL then convert NSAttributedString.